# Подскажите, как описать эту картинку в html, спасибо

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как описать эту картинку в html,спасибо.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>reviews</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title text">Отзывы
        <img src="Comment.png">
        <div class="line">  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title1">    
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Написать нужные теги и стили. Покажите что вы уже сделали и что конкретно не получается. Пока это похоже на «сделайте за меня»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```css
.card {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}

.card .top {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #7bb734;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.card .top .title {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.card .list {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 3px solid #7bb734;
  padding: 5px 3px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #777;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card .list .item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #222;
}

.card .list .item .info {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.card .list .item .source {
  display: inline;
  padding: 3px 4px;
  background: #7bb734;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.card .list .item .source:hover {
  background: #ff6700;
}

.card .list .item .message {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 95%;
  line-height: 1.15;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--------->
<div class="card">
  <div class="top">
    <span class="title">Отзывы</span>
    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="info">
        <span>Иван Иванов</span> <span>26.05.19</span>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="source">Дом в посёлке &laquo;Адмиралъ&raquo;</a>
      <div class="message">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In rutrum dignissim neque quis suscipit. Praesent risus urna, sagittis id velit pretium, commodo pellentesque massa.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="info">
        <span>Константин Константинопольский</span> <span>26.05.19</span>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="source">Коттедж &laquo;Виктория&raquo; в Южном посёлке</a>
      <div class="message">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In rutrum dignissim neque quis suscipit. Praesent risus urna, sagittis id velit pretium, commodo pellentesque massa.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

На будущее, не задавайте подобных вопросов.. Изучите HTML и CSS.
А то Ваш вопрос будет воспринят как "сделай за меня" и закрыт.

Comment: @ВадимДудко, читайте и практикуйте, чем больше будет опыта, тем меньше будет думать над "алгоритмом построения". Удачи в начинаниях)